# How to get access to a value inside a table inside array?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have this structure and I'm trying to access the last index:

```
table = { {[11] = 22}, {[255] = 1}, {[55] = 1000} }
```

I have tried this, but it returns me `nil`

```
print(table[#table][1])
```

how do I get that 1000 value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you use numeric keys it's actually `table[#table][55]`.

Comment: yeah i just figured that out
i guess i have to change my structure to something like this
{{index= 55, value = 1000}}

Comment: @jaiguru If the inner tables _always_ contain a single key-value pair, `local index, value = next( table[#table] )` will get the `1000` as `value` (but if you add more entries to the inner tables that won't work anymore as you might get any of those other entries instead). In most cases, your idea of using explicit known keys is preferable.